# I have a record Id that needs to be selected to be updated

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a simple issue I cannot figure out. I am trying to get the id of the record setup as a link to go to a second page that updates the record. I have the update working when I click on update it takes me to the record. I want the id to do the same.

```
<html>
<?php
require_once("../db_connect.php");


$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users");
$stmt->execute();
?>
<?php while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) { ?>

<table bgcolor=F2F2F2 width=1080 border='2'table-layout: fixed >
<br>
<tr> 
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Update</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Bio</th>

</tr>
<tr>
<?php echo  "<td>
              <a href='../update.php?id="  . $row['id'] .  "'>ID</a></td>"?>
<?php echo "<td>
              <a href='../update.php?id="  . $row['id'] .  "'>Update</a></td>"?>
    <td><?php echo $row['First Name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Last Name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Address']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Bio']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whats not working now? and What kind of links shoud that be `../update.php?id=`? Your sure you don't want `update.php?id=`

Comment: the <a href='../update.php?id="  . $row['id'] .  "'>Update</a></td>"?>  is the link to click on to select the record to be able to update the information. I need the id to do the same.

Comment: oh the ../ means that it is not in the same directory

Comment: I don't understand what your goal is and whats not working?

Comment: I need  "<td>". $row['id'] . "</td>" to be a hyperlink like the update and be able to get to the record. I get confused when I try turning it to  hyperlink like update then it errors out. That td shows me the record ID

Comment: Okay as far as i understand you want `$row['id']` to be a hyperlink like `Update` is, right? So what is not working? And to what should the id link?

Comment: <a href='../update.php?id="  . $row['id'] .  "'>  this links to the record I want to update. I want to be able to get the record number like 200 to show up and  link to update.php?id=" if I was to write it ike the update "<td><a href='../update.php?id="  . $row['id'] .  "'>ID </a></td>"?> like this it would not show the record ID number it will only show the word ID on every column. I want it to show record number not the word ID

Comment: what is the difference between this two line ?
<?php echo  "<td><a href='../update.php?id="  . $row['id'] .  "'>ID</a></td>"?> and
<?php echo "<td><a href='../update.php?id="  . $row['id'] .  "'>Update</a></td>"?>
???

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to figure out?

Comment: I got the answere below. I was trying to get the id to show record number and be the link to the update page

Comment: Yeah. . same as on how you put id on link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it is a good practice to put duplicated content into a function or variable and then call it when needed, to improve code readability & to save time/space.
I have also noticed many people struggling with new syntax so I have split the "one-liners" and left comments explaining how does new syntax works.

```
function col_gen($slug,$id=''){

     return (!empty($id))? // If ID parameter exist and not empty generate column with a link
                '<td><a href="../update.php?id='.$id.'">'.$slug.'</a></td>': //else
                '<td>'.$slug.'</td>';
}
```

And then, in your case, you can run this function inside a loop:

....

```
     foreach($row as $k=>$slug){

         echo ($k==='id')? //if key equals "id"
                   col_gen($slug,$slug) // Output column for ID 
                  .col_gen('Update',$slug) // Output column for keyword Update
                  :col_gen($slug); //else output just column with the slug

                  /**
                   * Learn one-line PHP, you will love it, once you understand it...
                   * Full Example Above:
                   * echo ($k==='id') ? col_gen($slug,$slug).col_gen('Update',$slug):col_gen($slug);
                   **/
     }
```

Comment: I need it to show record number not the word ID. I left coment above that I did it this way but did not get results I wanted. I need the record number like 200 to show up instead of the word ID.

Comment: <?php $id = $row['id'];?>
<?php echo  "<td> <a href='../update.php?id=$id'>$id</a></td>"?> I did it like this and it worked thank you will accept answer.

Comment: @Veronica yeah that is correct that's why I'm confuse why not try the code first before your comment. You need to like his answer to remove the down voted.

Comment: @edrich oh I was out just got home and tried his code and it worked everything is good now. Thank you for the help.

Comment: 4 Years on, I have read my old answer and got tears on my face of laughing...
Dear reader, please accept my apologies, I hope the corrections above will help you in your journey ahead.